# Background thread with HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service exposed which validates the parameters and returns true/false accordingly and run a background thread to process results. For that, I have tried to do it with the HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem but it gives me the following error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Code is given below:

```
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{
    public async Task<bool> SearchAsync(UserSearch search, string email)
    {
        //Some operations
        var searchManager = new SearchManager();
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => searchManager.PerformSearch(search, email));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any codez to show?  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following :

```
var thread = new Thread(
                async () =>
                {
                    await searchManager.PerformSearch(search, email);
                }) {IsBackground = true};

            thread.Start();
```

Any better option please do let me know.